# What is local Bitcoin?

Tags: localbitcoins

I was listening to the Pompliano podcast and there was this really awesome guy talking about how he has been able to use local Bitcoin to stay afloat in amidst a collapsing economy and society in his home nation of Venezuela.

He shared how others like him have been able to survive economically thanks to local Bitcoin, but what is local Bitcoin? Where can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalBitcoins is a service that allows you to trade BTC with real money. The difference between it and other exchanges is that LocalBitcoins staff themselves don't buy or sell, but its users set their trading fee, price, and the currency, and to buy or sell bitcoins the site allows you to find a merchant-user.

A local Bitcoin does not exist. The BTC blockchain is a whole and only meaningful if it's together.